# Linking OpenSSL libraries to a program

Tags: linux, gcc, openssl

I have built OpenSSL from source (an intentionally old version; built with `./config && make && make test`) and would prefer to use what I have built without doing `make install` to link against my program.

The command that's failing is:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -static -Lopenssl/openssl-0.9.8k/ -lssl -lcrypto 
-Iopenssl/openssl-0.9.8k/include -o myApp source1.o source2.o common.o`
```

And I receive a series of errors similar to:

```
common.c:(.text+0x1ea): undefined reference to `SSL_write'
```

This makes me think there's something funky with my OpenSSL.  If I omit `-Lopenssl/openssl-0.9.8k/` from my command, the error changes to being unable to:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
```

Am I compiling OpenSSL incorrectly?  Or how should I best resolve this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Silly "Linux-isms" strike again!  Apparently, I need to change my command such that the `-L` and `-l` stuff is **at the end** like (despite what `man gcc` seems to indicate):

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -static -o myApp source1.o source2.o common.o -Lopenssl/openssl-0.9.8k/ -lssl -lcrypto -Iopenssl/openssl-0.9.8k/include`

Comment: It's the `-lssl -lcrypto` that need to be at the end.  When a library is scanned by the linker, only the functions for which there are already undefined references are linked.  So you need to put the "consuming" objects at the start of the link line, and the "supplying" objects at the end.

Comment: I'm always weird about accepting my own answers.  I'll switch it now though.

Comment: How does it differ for clan llvm?

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you want to use `make install`? It can copy generated binaries in the directory you want if you previously passed it to `./configure --prefix $HOME/target_library_install_directory`

If you used this trick with every library you build and install, you could then add the target directory to the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable and avoid using -L option.

Comment: This is good to know, but I'm not sure it's easier than just moving around where I put my `-L`.  Up-voted, nonetheless.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this as the answer as it's likely the right way to do it.  In my particular case, I didn't want everyone that checked out my code (and the modified OpenSSL code) to have to do anything but `make`.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Autotools, or you are building an Autools project like `cURL`, then you should be able to use `pkg-config`. The idea is the Autotools package will read OpenSSL's package configuration and things will "just work" for you.

The OpenSSL package configuration library name is `openssl`.

You would use it like so in a makefile based project.

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -o $@ -c `pkg-config --cflags openssl` $^

target: foo.o bar.o baz.o
        $(CC) -o $@ `pkg-config --libs openssl` $^
```

Also see [How to use pkg-config in Make](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28533059/608639) and [How to use pkg-config to link a library statically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27586503/608639).

Comment: thanks for this answer about `pkg-config`. Can you explain like i'm five, what the `pkg-config` is and how exactly it works? how its achieved that it auto-magically just find all links to include dirs etc. Of course I could use it like magic but its great to know how it works internally

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `pkg-config` to preserve compatibility. This is an example of `makefile` when needs to link `OpenSSL`.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = \
    -I. \
    -D_GNU_SOURCE=1

LDFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs inih`
LDFLAGS += `pkg-config --libs libcurl`
LDFLAGS += `pkg-config --libs liburiparser`
LDFLAGS += `pkg-config --libs openssl`


# Executable
foo: foo.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)


foo.o: foo.c 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```