# Implementation for EVP_CipherInit_ex / EVP_CipherUpdate / EVP_CipherFinal_ex

Tags: c++, ubuntu, openssl, cryptoapi

I am using OpenSSL and `libcrypto` for encryption. I would like to ask where can I find these methods. I need them because i would like to add these methods in my code. I just want the .h and .cc or .c files. appreciate

Comment: The are in the `<openssl src>/crypto` folder. Look for `evp.h` and one of the associated source files. Possible duplicate of [Linking OpenSSL libraries to a program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352573/linking-openssl-libraries-to-a-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is detailed information on how to compile the openssl library yourself:
http://www.ski-epic.com/2007_notes_on_openssl/index.html

You can download the source code from here:
http://www.openssl.org/

Simply search the code for implementations of the functions you are referring to, and copy/paste. Make sure the library's license allows you to do this, though.