# How to use pkg-config in Make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gtk

I want to compile the simplest GTK program. 
I can compile it using the command line:

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)  main.c -o main.o
```

However, if I use Make it doesnt work:

```
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra $(pkg-config --cflags)
LDFLAGS=$(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
CC=gcc

SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)
EXECUTABLES=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(SOURCES))

all: $(EXECUTABLES)
```

It tells me this:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra    -c -o main.o main.c
main.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Where do I stick $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) in the Makefile to make it compile?

Thanks very much in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145132/makefiles-how-can-i-use-them/20146082#20146082)

Comment: Not quite; this does show a fix if you look hard enough. Keep this comment anyway.

Comment: More an alternative than an answer, but maybe you can consider using CMake instead of plain Makefiles. It has a much better syntax and is cross-platform.

Answer (score 53):

There are two issues.

First, your `CFLAGS` line is wrong: you forgot to say `gtk+-3.0` in the `pkg-config` part, so `pkg-config` will spit out an error instead:

```
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)
```

Second, and more important, `$(...)` is intercepted by make itself for variable substitution. In fact, you've seen this already:

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)
EXECUTABLES=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(SOURCES))

all: $(EXECUTABLES)
```

is all done by make.

There are two things you can do.

First, you can use `` `...` `` instead, which does the same thing (`$(...)` is newer shell syntax).

```
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`
LDFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Second, since you seem to be using GNU make, you can use the `shell` substitution command, which was shown in the answer Basile Starynkevitch linked above:

```
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra $(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)
LDFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
```

Comment: And make helpfully doesn't warn about undefined variables/functions :) Cost me an hour thinking I new how to write a simple makefile ^^

Comment: Another way is to escape the `$` character: `$$(pkg-config --libs module)`.