# how to add pkg-config to a Makefile?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, mongo-c-driver

My Makefile looks like this :

```
all:main.cpp
    g++ -I../../DrAPI/ -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -lrt -o SampleApp01 $< 
clean:
    rm -f SampleApp01
```

this is what I would do without Makefile:

```
gcc main.cpp -o test $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongoc-1.0)
```

now because of importing DrAPI I have to use Makefile to include that API as well, but I would lose libmongoc-1.0 without pkg-config. In that case, how should I add $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongoc-1.0) into my Makefile so that it works?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533059/how-to-use-pkg-config-in-make.

Comment: Summary from the linked answer: you may also use $(shell [command[) if the backticks do not work.

Comment: This use of `pkg-config` is not properly used, only half way there.  You only add libraries with the `-l` switch, but not in which directory they are stored, which is the `-L` switch.
It might, or might not work.  Depending how your libraries you use are set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`` all:main.cpp
    g++ -I../../DrAPI/ `pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongoc-1.0` -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -lrt -o SampleApp01 $< 
clean:
    rm -f SampleApp01 ``

Comment: I don't understand your answer, can you be more specific on how you add this to a makefile ? Thank you

Comment: using the back tick ` you can invoke another shell command and substitute its result to the place. I'd ask you to be more specific also about what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you very much, It is the first time I'm using a pkg-config in a makefile, and I'm not sure on how to use the synthax, to have it work properly. So I should I use your synthax after LIBS= in my makefile

Comment: This is not about `makefile`, this is about `shell`. But yes, you can try using it when assigning `LIBS` variable

Answer (score 4):

I would have made a `Makefile` that looks like this, so it use the 
rules that are already in `make(1)`.
Try `make -f /dev/null --print-data-base` to see them. Suggest `grep`-ing `COMPILE.c` and `LINK.c` to get the important stuff. `COMPILE.cpp`, `COMPILE.C` and `COMPILE.cxx` are for c++ and `COMPILE.c` are for c.

```
#!/bin/make
# Makefile
# 2020-02-10 Anders Jackson

# Basic setup
CXX       = g++
CXXFLAGS  = -c -g -Wall -Wextra
CXXFLAGS += -I../../DrAPI/
LDFLAGS   =
LDLIBS    = -ldl -lrt

# `pkg-config --list-all | grep -e mongo` will find if installed
# Here is the libmongoc-1.0 setup.
CXXFLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags          libmongoc-1.0`
LDFLAGS  += `pkg-config --libs-only-L     libmongoc-1.0`
LDLIBS   += `pgk-config --libs-only-other libmongoc-1.0`
LDLIBS   += `pkg-config --libs-only-l     libmongoc-1.0`

# Adjusting for this project
SOURCES = main.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

EXECS = main

all: $(EXECS)      # Link exec from objects
$(OBJECTS):        # Make all .o from .cpp (no local header files)

clean:
      -rm $(OBJECTS)
      -rm $(EXECS)
# eof
```

Notice that here there that object files only has dependencies on the source file.  If a source file has some local header file dependencies, you need to add them manually.

This file also see to that when linking, those `-L` switches are before object files and `-l` switches are after.
If you try to just use just one `pkg-config --libs` in `LDFLAGS`, it will not work.
I also just add one thing at the time to the variables with `+=`, like for `LDLIBS`, as it makes it easier to see what is added.

The built in rules are:

```
OUTPUT_OPTION = -o $@
# Compilation for C and C++
COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
COMPILE.cpp = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
# Linking for C and C++
LINK.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
LINK.cpp = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

It helps to understand which variable goes where.

Answer (score 1):

When I compile my C code using the GTK+ library I create a variable called `GTK` and set it to `pkg-config` like this:

```
GTK = `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Compiling the code using:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(GTK) -o $@
```

Where `CC = gcc`, `CFLAGS` are some other compiler flags (like `-I ../../DrAPI`) and `OBJECTS` are the source and object files.

This way your makefile could look like this:

```
DRAPI = `pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongoc-1.0`

all:main.cpp
    g++ -I../../DrAPI/ -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -lrt $(DRAPI) -o SampleApp01 $< 
clean:
    rm -f SampleApp01
```

**EDIT**: Forget about this. Use a `CFLAGS` variable and store `pkg-config --cflags [some library, eg. gtk+-3.0]` and a `LIBS` variable to store `pkg-config --libs [some library again]`. Now your makefile could look like this:

```
CFLAGS = -I../../DrAPI/ -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -lrt `pkg-config --cflags libmongoc-1.0`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs libmongoc-1.0`

all:main.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o SampleApp01 $< 
clean:
    rm -f SampleApp01
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would just set `CC=g++` and then all is set up.  The `all` rule should point to the binary to build, not the source.  So `all:main` would be all needed for `all`.  No need to tell `make` how to compile and link c code. It already know that.