# How are you supposed to know what library names are

Tags: compilation, linker, shared-libraries, pkg-config

When using a tool like pkg-config (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533059/how-to-use-pkg-config-in-make/28533513)), how is one supposed to know what the library name should be? It is not always intuitive. DLIB, for example, doesn't work for

- `pkg-config --cflags dlib`
- `pkg-config --cflags libdlib`
- `pkg-config --cflags dlib-19.9`

I usually have to issue a command like `sudo ldconfig -p | grep dlib`, but all that does is return `libdlib.so`, which also doesn't work.

How do experts tackle this problem. Do they simply know all the library names?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is called **package name** what you are using as a main parameter for pkg-config, and then applying **--cflags** or **--libs**, etc one just accesses the parameters specified and evaluated from the corresponding *package config file* ([some_package_name].pc, a.k.a *pkg-config metadata file*) that was found in [pkg-config search paths](http://ilgthegeek.old.livius.net/2015/02/05/pkg-config-search-path/).

And yes, there is no rule how package name relates to library name. Typically it's either library name without **lib-** prefix or just the whole library name. I found the following in [pkg-config guide](https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html):

> A common choice is to match the library name to the .pc name.
>   For instance, a package installing libfoo.so would have a
>   corresponding libfoo.pc file containing the pkg-config metadata. This
>   choice is not necessary; the .pc file should simply be a unique
>   identifier for your library. Following the above example, foo.pc or
>   foolib.pc would probably work just as well.

However, you can list all available in pkg-config search paths and find out the correct names before using them in Makefile:

```
$ pkg-config --list-all | grep dlib
```