# cannot open source file "glibconfig.h" (dependency of "gtk/gtk.h") in Studio Code

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, gtk

I've configured the task json in Visual Studio Code

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/lib64/ccache/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "`pkg-config", "--cflags", "--libs","gtk+-3.0`"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/lib64/ccache"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And I think the terminal output is ok,it builds without issues:

```
> Executing task: /usr/lib64/ccache/gcc -g /home/giuliohome/dev/gnome/gtk-example/gtk_hello02.c -o /home/giuliohome/dev/gnome/gtk-example/gtk_hello02 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` <
```

For a strange reason, that I don't deeply understand, the Visual Studio Code editor needs a different, separate configuration in `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` and it still complains with **squiggles** under the `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`

Message of the problem explains:

> cannot open source file "`glibconfig.h`" (dependency of "`gtk/gtk.h`")

What I've tried to do was already adding 3 dirs by visual inspection of my `/usr/inlcude` structure

but (since it contains a lot of file and subfolders) I'm perplexed by this way to proceed (I'm I supposed to keep searching all those nested include dependencies?) and anyway I don't know what to add next...

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/linux",
                "/usr/include/gtk-3.0",
                "/usr/include/glib-2.0"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/lib64/ccache/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I was able to get the error to go away by adding the following to the `includePath`:

```
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/include/glib-2.0",
            "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include"
        ],
```

Comment: For CentOS 8, add `/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include/` into `includePath` fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

After two years, this is still an [open issue of Studio Code](https://github.com/hiroMTB/vscode_oF/issues/5).

It is obvious that it is not manageable, anyway, for your info, this is the solution on my Fedora 31 Linux workstation:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/linux",
                "/usr/include/gtk-3.0",
                "/usr/include/glib-2.0",
                "/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include",
                "/usr/include/pango-1.0",
                "/usr/include/harfbuzz",
                "/usr/include/cairo",
                "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
                "/usr/include/atk-1.0"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/lib64/ccache/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```