# How to fix ../libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `rc4_md5_enc'?

Tags: linux, openssl, arm, cross-compiling, openwrt

I am trying to cross compile openssl for ARM on 64bit ubuntu.
I am getting following errors

```
: undefined reference to `BIO_f_zlib'
../libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `rc4_md5_enc'
../libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `mod_exp_512'
```

Please tell me how to rectify this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352573/linking-openssl). Otherwise, we need more information, like how you configured OpenSSL, how you cross-compiled it, what a typical compile command looks like, what the link command looks like, etc.

Comment: i am cross-compiling openssl-1.0.1f for arm architecture. I followed this link to do so http://www.streamboard.tv/oscam/wiki/crosscompiling. Check the " How to install openssl/libcrypto " part.

Comment: @jww Did u check the link ??

Comment: NO. Please provide the required information with the question. But you can check `../libcrypto.so` does (or does not) provide the symbol with `nm -D ../libcrypto.so | grep rc4_md5_enc`. You should see it listed with a ***capitol T*** if its exported. It will be a ***lower t*** if its present but not exported.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I'm building the plain 1.0.1 branch targeting `linux-generic32` though in a `linux-x86_64` environment - I have done the `nm` test you suggested and it shows a `U` beside the entry for `rc4_md5_enc`

Answer (score 3):

not sure if it helps but did you tried running **./Configure linux-x86_64**

Comment: According to Openssl docs, linux-generc64 and linux-generic32 is not complete as well as linux-x86_64 and so on. So, try to use linux-x86_64