# Linking C files Error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c, linker

I have three files, rsa.c, prf.c, and rsa-test.c.

I use `gcc -c rsa.c`, `gcc -c prf.c`, `gcc -c rsa-test.c` to get the .o files.

**EDIT**: I included rsa.c and prf.c in rsa-test.c.

Then I compile the .o files using `gcc -o test rsa.o prf.o rsa-test.o`.

I get the following error when I compile the. o files of three files.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_EVP_sha512", referenced from:
      randBytes(unsigned char*, unsigned long) in prf.o
  "_HMAC", referenced from:
      randBytes(unsigned char*, unsigned long) in prf.o
  "_SHA512", referenced from:
      setSeed(unsigned char*, unsigned long) in prf.o
  "___gmpz_add_ui", referenced from:
      randBytes(unsigned char*, unsigned long) in prf.o
  "___gmpz_clear", referenced from:
      rsa_shredKey(_RSA_KEY*) in rsa.o
  "___gmpz_export", referenced from:
      zToFile(__sFILE*, __mpz_struct*) in rsa.o
  "___gmpz_import", referenced from:
      zFromFile(__sFILE*, __mpz_struct*) in rsa.o
  "___gmpz_init", referenced from:
      rsa_initKey(_RSA_KEY*) in rsa.o
      setSeed(unsigned char*, unsigned long) in prf.o
  "___gmpz_limbs_read", referenced from:
      randBytes(unsigned char*, unsigned long) in prf.o
  "___gmpz_limbs_write", referenced from:
      rsa_shredKey(_RSA_KEY*) in rsa.o
  "___gmpz_set_ui", referenced from:
      rsa_initKey(_RSA_KEY*) in rsa.o
      setSeed(unsigned char*, unsigned long) in prf.o
  "___gmpz_size", referenced from:
      zToFile(__sFILE*, __mpz_struct*) in rsa.o
      rsa_numBytesN(_RSA_KEY*) in rsa.o
      rsa_shredKey(_RSA_KEY*) in rsa.o
      randBytes(unsigned char*, unsigned long) in prf.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error. The linker seems like the problem, because I'm using functions from rsa.c and prf.c in rsa-test.c and that's what's causing this problem.

Please let me know if you would like to test my files, I will post them up.

Comment: Maybe you have to link some libraries using `-l` option.

Comment: windows from the extra leading underscore character in the symbols ?  `gcc -o test rsa.o prf.o rsa-test.o -lgmp -lcrypto` where gmp.dll is GMP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library  and crypto.dll is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link to the libraries you're using by adding link flags to the `gcc -o` command.

It looks like you're using GMP, so that flag should be `-lgmp`.

If the other library involved is OpenSSL, try `-lcrypto` or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352573/linking-openssl-libraries-to-a-program) if you built it from source.

```
gcc -o test_linked.exe rsa.o prf.o rsa-test.o -lgmp -lcrypto
```

Answer (score 1):

While linking you should include libraries or shared libraries along with optionla library path with -L option an example of such

```
gcc -o binary *.o -L /path/to/libraries -llibrary
```

where -llibrary will look something like this

```
liblibrary.so or liblibrary.so*
```