# How to use openssl in cygwin?

Tags: compilation, openssl, c

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Everytime i try to run my code with these libraries i get this error. Not sure what to do.

```
fatal error: openssl/pem.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here. You can ask programming questions on [so], but you'll need to provide full information. In particular, how you're compiling (copy-paste the compiler command line).

Comment: You should show the command you are using to compile your program. I'm guessing your next question will be answered by [Linking OpenSSL libraries to a program](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4352573/608639).