# Which libraries are needed for openssl's BIGNUM?

Tags: c, openssl, linker, mingw

I need to generate RSA keys and it seems like `openssl` is the most common library that supports keys of length 3072. *MinGW* seems to come with pre-compiled libraries for it, so I tried linking `-lcrypto` and `-lssl`. However, when I just try to use

```
BIGNUM* someBigNum = BN_new();
```

I got the following error:

```
undefined reference to `BN_new'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What other library do I need to link?

Comment: What did you do to find out? Did you at least type the function name into your favorite web search engine?

Comment: @the-busybee Typing 'Openssl bignum linking' into google doesn't yield any relevant results and just typing 'openssl linking' yields posts like https://www.unix.com/programming/162567-linking-openssl-libcrypto-statically.html https://help.perforce.com/sourcepro/current/HTML/index.html#page/Rogue_Wave_Component_Builder_(RCB)/rcbbd-securecomm.18.5.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352573/linking-openssl-libraries-to-a-program all of which only mention lcrypto and lssl regardless of verion or OS

Comment: Well, please put these information into your question by [edit]ing, so that we know what we need not to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

`BN_new` is part of `-lcrypto`, but on Windows you may need to use `-leay32`